# Why and I getting a 500 error although my python script appears to work?

Tags: python-2.7, wsgi

```
#!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\python\python.exe"
import os,sys,cgi
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
json = form.getvalue("json")
file = open("testjson.json", "w")

file.write(json)

file.close()

print json

sys.exit()
```

I am running Python 2.7.2 as WSGI and other scripts appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last HTTP header should be followed by blank line. (The header and body should be separated by blank line)

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print # <---- Add this line

...

# sys.exit() <--- This is not needed.
```